# Kohana3.3: check if session exists from another action

Tags: session, action, kohana, session-variables, kohana-3

I have

```
Session::$default='database';
$session=Session::instance();
```

and
`$session->id()` displays session's value now. 
The value is stored in the `sessions` table as well.
Everything seems to work fine.

My question is: how to check if session exists in another action.
The `$_SESSION` array is undefined.

Comment: What do mean? You dont need to check Kohana sessions for existance, just call `Session::instance()` cause its a Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the session from any controller action or view template, simply use:

```
Session::instance()
```

For example:

```
$session = Session::instance();

$session->set('my_key', 'my_value');

// returns false if my_key does not exist
$my_key = $session->get('my_key', false);
```

To overload $_SESSION with the Kohana session, run the following inside each action method:

```
$_SESSION =& $session->as_array();
```